# Invoking child method in PHP OOP

Tags: php, inheritance

I am creating a set of classes for testing some data - I have a base class `Test`:

```
class Test {
    protected $data;
    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    public function Run() {}
}
```

And then a series of classes which extend *Test*, such as `TestForX`:

```
class TestForX extends Test { 
    public function Run() {
        // do test code
    }
}
```

I'd like to add some timing to my Run method. I know I could add methods for `startTiming` and `endTiming` to my base class and call `parent::startTiming()` and `parent::endTiming()` in my extended classes, but I've already written a load of tests.

Is it possible to turn this round, and use something like `child::Run` in my base class?

```
class Test {
    public function Run() {
        $this->startTime = microtime(true);
        child::Run();
        $this->endTime = microtime(true);
    }
}
```

This would allow me to keep my child classes clean by wrapping methods in the base. At the moment, I'm getting around it by having a base class for `Test::Go` which calls `$this->Run()`.

Comment: This doesn't look like phpunit. Does your testing framework have the concept of a test method startUp() and tearDown() method? If so, I would put it there in the base class, though you would incur timing overhead from the test framework itself.

Comment: Thanks, but it's for testing document structure - eg a DOM - not unit testing.

Comment: FWIW, your class `Test` should not have a method called `Test`; that's the old-but-still-supported way to declare a constructor and will bite you in the rear end some day.

Comment: Thanks @deceze, good point. I'll update my question.

Comment: How do you expect parent `Test` be invoked, if the child have it's own `Test` method?

Comment: Also, no need to call `parent::startTiming`, `$this->startTiming` will do just fine. – And no, if you're overriding method `Test` in child classes, this is not possible. You will need to use another method name, or restructure your general logic.

Comment: What stops you from defining your Test class as an abstract with an asbtract TestChild method? And then you can call Test() of your parent class implementation. In the Test() you can call $this->TestChild();

Comment: @vahan, the issue is that method 'test' is what is defined in the child classes and it overrides the same method in the base class. PHP will only execute one method called 'test' that it finds after searching the hierarchy.  i.e.  the child method will have to explicitly call the 'parent method' to have it run.

Comment: @RyanVincent I beleive it is not possible. First of all it is bad design to asume that child class overrides a method. The only way to do so is to define parent method as abstract but in this case you just can't. The Run() method is already implemented in the parent class.

Comment: @vahan, It seems we agree on the issues with the OP class definitions? :) I agree with your statements about 'less than flexible design'

Comment: @RyanVincent, definitely ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are free to change the call to your test classes, you could add an other function that wraps your behaviour

```
public function runTest(){
    $this->startTime = microtime(true);
    $this->Test();
    $this->endTime = microtime(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my question, I've said that this is what I'm currently doing.

Comment: I believe Joffrey proposed to add `runTest()` to the parent class.

Comment: @AlexBlex in my question, I describe "having a base class for Test::Go which calls $this->Run()" - I do appreciate the effort Joffrey has gone to, but it does duplicate what I've already said.

Comment: @AdamHopkinson you have edited the question after the answer and my comment on it, so I repeat it again for the new edition - there is no way to call parent method `Test::Run` if it is overridden by child's `TestForX::Run` unless you call it explicitly by `parent::Run` within the child class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible to call child method that have the same name as the parent one. First of all it is bad design to assume that child class overrides a method. To enforce a child class to implement a method is to define a parent abstract method but in this case you just can't. The Run() method is already implemented in the parent class.

You should use abstraction and use a different name.

Here is a possible implementation that may work for you. You can just define your base class as an abstract class, *TestForX* will extend *Test* class and you will call *Run()* on the instance of the *TestForX*.

```
abstract class Test {
    protected $data;
    abstract public function RunChild();

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    public function Run() {
        $this->startTime = microtime(true);
        $this->RunChild();
        $this->endTime = microtime(true);
    }    
}

class TestForX extends Test { 
    public function RunChild() {
        // do test code
    }
}
```